# Linux command - adding Time elements to file name

Tags: linux, shell, date

I run regular backups of my phpbb forum files from the command line:

```
now=$(date +"%m%d%Y")
zip -r phpbb_complete_file_backup_$now  ~/public_html/forum/*
```

I'd like to add the hour and minutes to the file name (24 hour clock, sync'd to Pacific Standard Time, if possible). How would I do that?

Comment: Have you tried running `man date`?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about man date, didn't know about this resource in linux

Answer (score 1):

Ummm ...

```
now=$(date +"%m%d%Y-%H%M")
zip -r phpbb_complete_file_backup_$now ~/public_html/forum/*
```

**man date** for details.